# How do I stop this fast factorization program from printing beyond the 3rd output?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, printing, calculation

I have a problem with this python37 code during printing and I would like it not to **print out the primes** in the output for the factorization.  However I would like it to print just the composites **not beyond the 3rd print statement** of the loop.  The program is super fast for a factorization of large composites but slow for large primes.

For example 3 prints like this:

The factors of 3 are:
1,
3

If I input 2047 it prints like this:

The factors of 2047 are:
1,
23,
89,
2047

However I would just like it to show up to 89.  Here is the code:

```
    import math
    while True:
        def print_factors(x):
           print("The factors of",x,"are:")
           for i in range(1,x+1):
               if x % i == 0:
                   print(i)



        p = int(input('Enter a prime number and if the output is 1 and itself its prime: '))


        k = ((p**2*2))
        l = (((pow(2, k + 1, 2 * k) - 1) % (2 * k)))
        f = (k//2//p)
        print_factors(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with help from Gribouillis at the python io forum, but the primes still print, however the cutoff is below the 4th output. You can generate factors and slice the iterator!

```
    import itertools as itt
    while True: 
        def gen_factors(x):
            for i in range(1, x + 1):
                if x % i == 0:
                    yield i

        def print_factors(x, maxcnt=None):
            g = gen_factors(x)
            if maxcnt is not None:
                g = itt.islice(g, 0, maxcnt)
            for p in g:
                print(p)
        p = int(input('Enter a prime number and if the output is 1 and itself 
        its prime: '))
        p = (2**p-1)
        k = ((p**2*2))
        f = (k//2//p)
        if __name__ == '__main__':
             print_factors(p, 3)
```